# Remove and shift array c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to locate a specific item from an array and then shift the array to remove that item. I have a list of integers {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9} and want to remove the integer 2.

Currently I am getting an error: storage size of ‘new_ints’ isn’t known on the line:

```
int new_ints[];
```

Not sure what this means or how can I fix this?

Here is my code:

```
int main() {

  int tmp = 2;
  int valid_ints[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

  int new_ints[];
  new_ints = stripList(tmp, valid_ints);

  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(new_ints); i++)
    cout << new_ints[i] << endl;

  return 0;
}


int *stripList (int tmp, int valid_ints[]){

  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(valid_ints); i++){
    for (int j = tmp; j < sizeof(valid_ints); j++){
      valid_ints[j] = valid_ints[j+1];
    }
  }
  return valid_ints;
}
```

Comment: The Compiler claims correctly, you didn't specify a compile time available size for your array here: `int new_ints[];`. You rather want to use a `std::vector<int>` instead.

Comment: Use `std::vector` and `std::remove`.

Comment: You can't use an array as tha target of an assignment -- `new_ints = ...` is not valid.

Comment: And there's no reason for `stripList` to return the array, since it updates the array in place.

Comment: Inside the `stripList` function, `valid_ints` is a pointer, not an array. So `sizeof(valid_ints)` is the size of a pointer, not the number of elements in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like what Ben said, it is highly recommended to use an vector if you would like to resize your array to fit in new elements.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/

Here's my example: (note alternatively you can use vector::erase to erase undesired elements)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  vector<int> valid_ints;
  vector<int> new_ints;

  int tmp = 2;

  //read in elements
  for(int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
  {
    valid_ints.push_back(i);
  }
  //valid_ints will hold {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}

  for(int i = 0; i < valid_ints.size(); i++)
  {
    //We will add an element to new_ints from valid_ints everytime the valid_ints[i] is NOT tmp. (or 2.)
     if(valid_ints[i] != tmp)
     {

       new_ints.push_back(valid_ints[i]);
     }
  }

  //Print out the new ints
  for(int i = 0; i < new_ints.size(); i++)
  {
    cout << new_ints[i] << ' ';
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The resulting vector will be filled in this order:

{1}

{1,3} (skip 2!)

{1,3,4}

{1,3,4,5}

so on... until

{1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}

**So, the output would be:**

1 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Answer (score 1):

In `c++` size of an `array` must be known at compile time. Ie `int new_ints[]` is illegal. You will need to have a defined size ie `new_ints[10]`. (See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array) for more details) Or better yet, utilize the fantastic advantages of `c++` and use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: He also needs to pass the size of the array to `stripList`, because `sizeof(valid_ints)` will be `sizeof(int*)`.